# How to stream audio from encrypted version of mp3 file using Java REST server?

Tags: java, spring, rest, audio-streaming, dropwizard

We have audio files which should be streamed to authenticated users. All the audios are encrypted.

Our current approach is to decrypt file download in a public web directory on the server which has the file name in a predefined format. If called using link this file is playable on any client i.e. web or mobile. But we have security challenges as this file is in public directory anyone with basic browser knowledge can get a link and play it without authentication.

Is there any secure way to stream an audio file using authentication? Any standard practice in Java REST frameworks, spring-boot, dropwizard etc?